QGIS GDAL Clip by Mask not working
I am trying to clip a raster by a shape mask in QGIS using GDAL but I keep getting the error
Process gdalwarp failed to start. Either gdalwarp is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to run the program.
Execution failed after 0.04 seconds

Even when I use GDAL Warp to just reproject rasters is does not work.
What should I do to fix this error?



Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than some only in a picture.

Feels like a bad installation of QGIS. Maybe the path does not include the directory where the GDAL utilities are.

Exactly the same issue. I'm using the Macports version of QGIS - maybe you are as well, but I think it is a PATH problem. The default PATH for QGIS is /usr/bin:[...] but MacPorts uses /opt/local/bin.
I went to QGIS -> Preferences -> System. In that panel near the bottom is a section called Environment. I enabled (checkbox) Use custom variables and then added the following change that when applied modifies the PATH variable:
For Apply I selected Prepend, for Variable, I typed PATH (note all uppercase) and for Value I typed /opt/local/bin: (note the trailing colon).
I restarted QGIS and then went back to QGIS -> Preferences -> System and verified that the PATH variable (under Current environment variables) was now set to /opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:  The GDAL tools that had failed with the same error you had are now working. I would check where your binaries for GDAL are (either in the App Bundle or /usr/local/ /opt/local - whatever - and explicitly add that location to your PATH.
I'd be awfully nice if OSGeo and QGIS programmers would spend more time creating a cross-platform build tool. New features are nice, but if the community fragments and can't build the application what use are those features.
